# SQL Server pagination with JOIN - Ambiguous column name 'id'

Tags: sql-server, join, pagination

i have trouble fixing one query which и normally use without JOIN , but now i want to JOIN couple of tables and i see one error for ambiguous column name id.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'id'.1

The code which i use:

```
SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id desc) 
            AS RowNumber,
            d.id as iddr, d.EGN, d.Names, d.NickName, d.Residence, d.PersonalMobilePhone, d.HomeAddress,d.GarantPerson, d.InsertDate, 
            t.id, t.PossitionName, 
            de.id, de.IdDriver, de.IdPAFirms,de.IdPossition 
            FROM dbo.Driver d 
            FULL JOIN dbo.DriversEmployed de ON d.id = de.IdDriver 
            FULL JOIN dbo.CompanyPossitions t ON de.IdPossition = t.id)
        AS TEST 
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1
```

If i try only JOIN into Management SQL studio the code JOIN succesfull. So i suppose the trouble `id` is here ORDER BY id clause.

Is there a way to use JOIN in this query?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to prefix the `id` with the proper table alias in the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS RowNumber
```

You need to indicate from which table the column `id` is from by prefixing it with the proper table alias, i.e.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.id DESC) AS RowNumber
```

Additionally, you need to assign different column alias to similar columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.id DESC) AS RowNumber,
        d.id AS iddr, -- Here
        d.EGN,
        d.Names,
        d.NickName,
        d.Residence,
        d.PersonalMobilePhone,
        d.HomeAddress,
        d.GarantPerson,
        d.InsertDate,
        t.id AS CompanyPossitionsId, -- Here
        t.PossitionName,
        de.id AS DriversEmployedId, -- Here
        de.IdDriver,
        de.IdPAFirms,
        de.IdPossition
    FROM dbo.Driver d
    FULL JOIN dbo.DriversEmployed de
        ON d.id = de.IdDriver
    FULL JOIN dbo.CompanyPossitions t
        ON de.IdPossition = t.id
) AS TEST
WHERE
    RowNumber BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1
```

Comment: Thank you, i try this but other error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'TEST'.1

Comment: Thank you, now i understand.

Answer (score 0):

Both your `Driver` and `CompanyPositions` tables have an `id` column, making the name `id` ambiguous. You should fully qualify it in your `order by` clause. E.g.:

```
ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: Thank you, i try this but other error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'TEST'.1